# Evaluate the limit of $\frac{\sin(7x)}{\sin(4x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to evaluate $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \pi }\frac{\sin(7x)}{\sin(4x)}$$ surely there must be some nice trick here?

L'hopital Rule is  not allowed here.

Comment: $sin(7\pi) / sin(4\pi) = 0/0 = 1$ QED

Comment: LHospital will do it.

Comment: 7 cos 7x / 4 cos 4x which go to 7/4 by hospitals rule

Answer (score 6):

Change variable $x=y+\pi$. So $$\frac {\sin(7x)}{\sin(4x)}=-\frac {\sin(7y)}{\sin(4y)}=-\frac 74\times\frac {\sin(7y)} {7y}\times\frac {4y} {\sin(4y)} $$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: @cr001.$x$ goes to $\pi$; so $y$ goes to $0$.

Comment: where is the minus from?

Comment: @Bak1139 It comes from $\sin(7y+7\pi)=-\sin(7y)$ while  $\sin(4y+4\pi)=+\sin(4y)$

Comment: @Bak1139 Since $x=y+\pi$, $7x=7y+7\pi$; and since $\sin(z+7\pi)=-\sin(z)$ for any $z$... (this explains why the numerator changes sign; why doesn't the denominator?)